# Should spoilers in tag wikis be edited out?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

While viewing the information on the [Resident Evil 5 tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/resident-evil-5/info) I noticed that the details contain what is potentially a spoiler (the bit about Jill).

Now arguably, in this instance, it may not be such a big spoiler. But what is the correct course of action should there be a major spoiler written in?

Comment: This particular tag wiki needs to be rewritten entirely, as it was plagarized off GameFAQs (or other).

Comment: wikipedia, apparently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was written there, the spoiler seemed completely gratuitous (provided it is a spoiler), so I've edited it out.

Spoilers in tag wiki excerpts seem like a waste of the premium space tag excerpts have. Tag wikis explain why you should and shouldn't use a tag and are not the place to explain the plot of a game.

Spoilers in tag wikis can be used if it makes sense to, however. Keep in mind that the spoiler syntax `>!` works there as well.